# KVM/QUEMU guest slow disk performance

Tags: linux, debian, kvm-virtualization, qemu, io

I'm really confused of QEMU/KVM behavior. I have a server - about 100GB RAM, 2 CPU - 6 core + HT, and three HDDs - one for root, and two for BTRFS-mirror for virtual machines (HGST HDN724030ALE640 if it's matter). OS - Debian 9.1, QEMU (disk type - raw, IO - native).

So, server is idle - it's run only one VM. This virtual machine (Debian 9.1, 16GB RAM, 4 VCPU), which runs PostgreSQL and MySQL databases. Queries receive only one - PostgreSQL (few insert per second). And... it takes lot of time, to do this inserts. I wrote simple script, which insert data to very simple table, whitout any constraints or indexes (three varchar fields). Script performance - about 1-2 inserts per second. It's extremely slow!

At first, I thought it's was Postgres trouble. But I rewrote my script for MySQL, and it shows same result. Then, I create new VM on FreeBSD, install PostgreSQL, create same database and table from Linux VM, and check performance again - 1-2 inserts per second.

Okay. Let's see on iostat and iotop. iotop shows, that Postgres process, which serves my insert queries, consume about 60-70% of IO (for simple inserts!) on VM. iostat -x says, that now uses about 40-45 writes/sec on VM, and about 80-90 w/s in host machine.

I tried to rate write speed with dd utility, like this:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/tmp/fooo.bar bs=1M count=1000
```

and it's done about 5-6 secs.

Next, while script execute about 100 inserts, I check

```
/proc/[Postgres_PID]/io file:

rchar: 138544
wchar: 114689
syscr: 39
syscw: 15
read_bytes: 0
write_bytes: 540672
cancelled_write_bytes: 0
```

What I'm doing wrong? Why I have so slow disk performance?

Comment: What is the filesystem inside the VM? What disk controller do you use? How is it configured (cache)? Your problem may be BTRFS fragmentation on top of something else. How much free space you have there (host and VM)? What mount options do you use? FYI: BTRFS has fragmentation issues when there's a lot of random writes. This makes virtualization/databases environments not performing well on hdd. How do you store guest filesystem in the host?

Comment: @MichalSokolowski, first, I need to say, that I'm not unix sysadmin. And I need do this job. :)

1. File system inside VM is BTRFS.
2. SATA.
3. I did not configure anything, just installed Debian.
4. On host I have  about 2TB free space, on VM I have about 10-20 GB free space. 

I think, you was right about BTRFS. I just read some related articles, and will try move my VMs on ext4 partition. Thanks for answer!

Comment: You should study this mail before trying anything else: https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-btrfs/msg68708.html

Comment: @MichalSokolowski, thank you very much for your advice about FS. I just copied VM on another HDD with ext4 (without any tuning yet) and IO performance increases in 5-10 times!